# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 100-101: illegal cp932 surrogate

Tags: python

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 520-521: illegal cp932 surrogate

とエラーが出ました。

```
import io
   with io.open('data/xxx2.csv', 'w', encoding='cp932') as fout:
        with io.open('data/xxx.csv', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
            fout.write(fin.read())
```

とコードを書きました。
utf-8で書かれたCSVファイルをcp932で書き出したいです。
エラーの意味もわからず520-521の位置だけおかしいと言われるのがわかりません。
どのように直せばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 入力ファイル `data/xxx.csv` にサロゲートペア文字列(例えば絵文字)が含まれているのではないでしょうか。`io.open()` の引数に `errors='surrogateescape'`(入力側), `errors='ignore'`(出力側) などを指定することでエラーは回避できるかも知れませんが、`cp932` エンコーディングに存在しない文字は無視するか、自前で適当な文字に変換するしかありません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/69196